# Python list join via Map() yields "None type" list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following statement, inspired by [Python tips: Map, Filter Reduce](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html):

```
globalTags = ['deviceName'\
    , 'processIndex'\
    , 'timingGroupID'\
    , 'sequenceIndex'\
    , 'chainIndex'\
    , 'eventNumber'\
    , 'chainStartStamp'\
    , 'acqStatus'\
    , 'sequenceStartStamp']

chargeTags = ['charge_status', 'charge_units']
chargeTags = list(map(lambda tag: chargeTags.append(tag), globalTags))
```

this yields `<class 'list'>: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` instead of the expected joined list comprising the values of the two initial lists. What am I doing wrong and what would be a better statement?

Comment: What's the expected output? `globalTags + chargeTags` ?

Comment: `.append()` doesn't return anything, it modifies the list in place.

Comment: What do you think `.append` returns? You should never use `map` for side effects

Comment: You don't need those backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate arrays with the `+` operator.

```
globalTags = [
    'deviceName',
    'processIndex',
    'timingGroupID',
    'sequenceIndex',
    'chainIndex',
    'eventNumber',
    'chainStartStamp',
    'acqStatus',
    'sequenceStartStamp'
]

chargeTags = ['charge_status', 'charge_units']
chargeTags = chargeTags + globalTags
```